# Getting pointer instead of string

Tags: python, file, pointers, filesystems

In my script, I have the following:

```
file = '%s/data.txt' % (theDirectory)
text = open(file)
theString = text.read
print 'Hello, %s' % (theString)
```

it returns this:

```
Hello, <built-in method read of file object at 0x100534a48>
```

What's causing this?

Comment: You should probably be using os.path.join instead of explicitly adding directory separators (it's more cross-platform).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *call* the method using parentheses:

```
theString = text.read()
```

Without the parentheses, Python assigns a reference to the method itself to `theString` (which isn't a string at all, at that point).

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace

```
theString = text.read
```

with:

```
theString = text.read()
```

because `text.read` is a function, or better is a `<built-in method read of file object at xxx>`,
instead `text.read()` calls that function and return a string.